# Site AngularJS acessando API, dúvida de autenticação

Tags: php, angularjs, api, autenticação, slim

Eu tenho uma API escrita em PHP + Slim, que está sendo utilizada por um painel administrativo, e a autenticação é via token, que é retornado quando o usuário do painel realiza o login.

No entanto, eu estou fazendo um site com Angular e gostaria de reaproveitar a API, mas não consegui entender como fazer o sistema de autenticação para o site, já que não tem como retornar um token para ele, pois não possui login.

Pensei em algo baseado no endereço do site, mas ainda não achei como fazer isso.

Qual é a melhor estratégia para realizar essa autenticação?

Desde já agradeço,

Muito obrigado

Comment: Talvez não faça autenticação nas rotas dos métodos que irão popular o site... Ou seja, crie controllers separados para o painel e para o site... na minha opinião...

Comment: Entendi @rpereira15 , mas nesse caso acabo deixando os dados GET da API abertos certo? Ou seja, já que não preciso de autenticação para popular os dados no site, posso tirar a autenticação das rotas GEt e deixar apenas nos POST e PUT, por exemplo... Obrigado

Comment: Na verdade depende muito de quais informações TODOS poderão ter acesso. Em um método get para usuários ou clientes ainda deverá ter autenticação...

Comment: Então aí que está o problema, a informação que vou compartilhar no site não deve ser aberta para que outra pessoa possa usar em seu aplicativo ou site por exemplo, pois a API é de um aplicativo, e não gostaria de deixar esses dados abertos.

Comment: Então estipula um token fixo e criptografado pro site, resolve o problema tb...

Comment: Opa muito obrigado cara, vou fazer isso. Agradeço pela ajuda

Answer (score 1):

Páginas com angular são paginas únicas, singlePage Applications (ou também conhecida como uma arquitetura stateless), a melhor forma de fazer autenticação em singlePage applications é usando JWT (Json web tokens)

Caso você tenha pensado em fazer o método tradicional de manter sessões como o HTTPSession da vida, não faz sentido usar isso em singlePageApp, pois o teu servidor só vai retonar uma única página e o resto vem dinâmico vide API.

Aconselho a você criar algum webservice que retorne um token e a cada requisição que o angular fazer ao servidor você envie um token junto do payload da requisição ou no header dela, tradicionalmente vejo muito o pessoal usando no header da requisição. Dai teu webservice vai verificar a veracidade do token passado (pode ser via banco de dados).

---

Resumo:

Requisição de login -> retorna um token se sucesso

resto das requisições que necessitam de autenticação -> leva esse token no header para um middleware ou metodo PHP autenticar

---

Dica:
Se você quer manter o usuario logado caso ele dê um ctrl + r (atualizar no browser a pagina) coloque esse token no sessionStorage do javascript, ou localStorage, ou $cookies do angular.

Espero ter ajudado, abraço.

Comment: Olá @PedroGabriel, obrigado pela resposta detalhada. Como posso fazer caso eu queira reaproveitar a mesma API em um site com AngularJS, já que o site não possui login?